# Magento 2.3.2 - Product import duplicates images

Tags: product, php, magento2.3, product-images, import

Running Magento 2.3.2 on PHP 7.2

CSV being uploaded has one image for base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image, swatch_image, additional_images.

When products are imported, product images are getting duplicated both in the backend and on the front end as follows.

**BACKEND**

[image]

**FRONTEND**

[image]

I found a possible solution at github https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21855

And used this [file](https://github.com/raivisdejus/magento2/blob/889ba5ae08cdebbd10915d6b22ef62fab10949f2/app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php) (there are more than 3000 lines of code, too long to post here)

I replaced the product.php file at

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import

with the file mentioned [above](https://github.com/raivisdejus/magento2/blob/889ba5ae08cdebbd10915d6b22ef62fab10949f2/app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php)

But when I try and import I get the following error.

> Warning:
>   hash_file(/home/xyz/abc/pub/media/catalog/product/v/v/vvg.jpg): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/xyz/abc/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php
>   on line 1778

How can I fix this issue of image duplication on import.

Comment: When you import product select option insert/update product ?

Comment: Using option Add/Update